# Unable to write content to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am trying to add some content to PDF using library called mpdf.

My code is

```
$template_data =$row['template_data'];

ob_end_clean(); 
include('\MPDF57\mpdf.php');

$mpdf=error_reporting(E_STRICT);
$mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',15,10,16,10,10,10);
$mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($template_data);
$mpdf->Output();

exit();
```

This code is working properly on localhost. But the problem is it's not working on the server. I have searched for the solution and the solution is that `mbstring` is not enabled on the server. After enabling this it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please give a link to the library.

Comment: Any errors are u getting ?

Comment: no errors are coming

Comment: So it does simply nothing on the server?

Comment: @nick library link is "http://hayagrivabizsolutions.net/svs/admin/MPDF57/"

Comment: Try to write some dummy data like `$template_data ='abcbadsd'` instead of  `$template_data =$row['template_data'];` and check if it works.

Comment: And also make sure, the path is properly included on server `include('\MPDF57\mpdf.php');`

Comment: i tried with dummy content all so but not working. and same path i am using  include('\MPDF57\mpdf.php');

Comment: if your server is linux based then use the dir path as like `include('/MPDF57/mpdf.php');` .

Comment: @jenis . no same thing nothing is coming. ( server is is linux based only and library is in - hayagrivabizsolutions.net/svs/admin/MPDF57

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78153/discussion-between-jenis-patel-and-nayana).

Comment: What about enabling error-reporting? Put this at the beginning of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solutions for your issue are as follows :

1. Firstly, if you are using linux based server then use the directory path as like `include('/MPDF57/mpdf.php');` instead of `include('\MPDF57\mpdf.php');`
2. Add `ob_start();` at the top of your script so that no output data will send to browser and then followed by `ob_end_clean();` as like below :

   `ob_start();
        $template_data =$row['template_data'];
       ob_end_clean();
       include('\MPDF57\mpdf.php');
       $mpdf=error_reporting(E_STRICT);
       $mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',15,10,16,10,10,10);
       $mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
       $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
       $mpdf->WriteHTML($template_data);
       $mpdf->Output();
       exit();`

hope it helps you.